# I want that kid to be kissed

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I was really powerful
>
> But then I almost dead like a fool
>
> I was a man with two faces at first
>
> and then just a memory, couldn't go worse
>
> Three, I want that kid to be kissed
>
> but he has flown away with the prisoner, didn't he?
>
> Four, I feel alive again now
>
> It's like I came back to life, wow!
>
> Seven, Seven of me I can make
>
> Anyway I've killed a snake
>
> I wanted to kill that kid so bad
>
> But I lost because I was mad

Now, I (Stever) wrote this riddle. But If I didn't, who would have written it?

This is a easy one, enjoy it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this refers to:

> The Harry Potter series. Lord Voldemort would have written this.

First three lines refer to:

> Book 1, Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone, where Lord Voldemort is left almost lifeless after attempting to kill Harry as a baby and then returns in the body of Quirell.

The next line refers to:

> Book 2, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, where Voldemort's memory tries to kill Harry.

The next two lines refer to:

> Book 3, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, where Harry escapes a dementor's kiss, and the prisoner, Sirius Black flies away on a Hippogriff.

The next two lines refer to:

> Book 4, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, when Voldemort regains a body.

The next line refers to:

> Book 7, Harry Potter and the deathly hallows, where the story is based on the seven horcruxes created by Voldemort that need to be destroyed.

The last two lines refer to:

> Voldemort's failed attempt to kill Harry.

Comment: That's the right answer! You were really fast!